# Maven integration in eclipse: Missing requirement

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

When I try to install this message comes up

> Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)
>         Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor 1.5.0.20140606-0033) requires 'bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo  changing the link has helped me  now it works .